# "error: ... patch does not apply" when editing hunk with "git add -p"

Tags: git, git-add, git-patch

tldr: why am I getting `error: ... patch does not apply` when editing a hunk and removing a line, even though it looks like it should work?

I'm editing a hunk while doing `git add -p`, where I want to only add `new line 1` (and not add `new line 2`):

```
# Manual hunk edit mode -- see bottom for a quick guide
@@ -1 +1,3 @@
 first line
+new line 1
+new line 2
# ---
# To remove '-' lines, make them ' ' lines (context).
# To remove '+' lines, delete them.
# Lines starting with # will be removed.
```

I changed the `+` to a space   for `new line 2`:

```
# Manual hunk edit mode -- see bottom for a quick guide
@@ -1 +1,3 @@
 first line
+new line 1
 new line 2
# ---
# To remove '-' lines, make them ' ' lines (context).
# To remove '+' lines, delete them.
# Lines starting with # will be removed.
```

but that gives the error:

```
error: patch failed: myfile:1
error: myfile: patch does not apply
Your edited hunk does not apply. Edit again (saying "no" discards!) [y/n]?
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the line instead.

Changing the `+` to a space   is **not** the correct action.
Per the directions given by git (`# To remove '+' lines, delete them.` ), what is needed is to **delete** `new line 2`:

```
# Manual hunk edit mode -- see bottom for a quick guide
@@ -1 +1,3 @@
 first line
+new line 1
# (^^^ note that "new line 2" has been deleted ^^^)
# ---
# To remove '-' lines, make them ' ' lines (context).
# To remove '+' lines, delete them.
# Lines starting with # will be removed.
```

Comment: You also must edit the header: I think `@@ -1 +1,3 @@` should become `@@ -1 +1,2 @@`

Comment: @phd: Git will re-count the lines, so that there's no need to edit the hunk-header.